# List all live events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I find in jQuery what events are bound with live for a particular element?

Say I have a function, `randomFunction`, that returns a random function from an array of functions.  How can I find which function has been bound to a certain element?

```
var arrayOfFunctions = []; //a whole bunch of functions
function randomFunction(array){}; //returns one of those functions
$('#certain_element').live('click', randomFunction(arrayOfFunctions));
```

What is the index of the array that corresponds to the function that was bound by `live` for `$('#certain_element')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, figured it out.
For a `click` event, for `$('#certain_element')`, logging each binding's index to the console:

```
var relevantHandlers = $.map($(document).data('events').live, function(value){
  if(value.origType == 'click' && value.selector == '#certain_element'){
    return value.handler;
  }
}; //all handlers for #certain_element bound to click by live.
$.each(relevantHandlers, function(){
  console.log("the index is: " + $.inArray(this, arrayOfFunctions));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/debug-jquery-events-with-listhandlers/). When I last used this, there was a need to slightly modify it for the then latest version of jQuery, but it should give you a direction.

Comment: That'll handle normal events bound with `.click` or `.bind`, but not `.live`

Answer (score 1):

There's a nifty bookmarklet called [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) that shows the code that will be called.

But since you're truly calling a random function, maybe doing something as simple as including an alert("function name") or colsone.log("function"), if you're just testing.

Comment: neat bookmarklet, but for `live` bindings it highlights the whole document but provides no information about what the target of the event has to be in order to trigger it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sence... the .live() event bubbles up to the root element before the .live trigger is called. I thought I was able to see the visual event on an <a> tag with a .live() bind, but it turns out I attached a delegate() to the <ul> the anchors were in. That worked.