# How to list all events attached to an element using jquery .live()?

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to list a list all events attached to a particular DOM element which had been attached using `live()`?

Comment: don't use .live() btw, it's evil

Comment: Don't use `live`, it's dead.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6144311/1430996

Comment: don't use `.live()`, it's dead and evil *from jquery 1.7 onward*. Use `$.on` and `$.off` with jquery 1.7+ instead. If you're using / have to use an older version fair enough. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: possible duplicate of [List all live events in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143474/list-all-live-events-in-jquery)

Comment: @jammypeach Actually if you use jQuery 1.4.2 or higher, you should use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). And if you're below 1.4.2, well you shouldn't be using jQuery. :) Avoid the evils of `.live()`. _"It's not the droid you're looking for."_

Comment: as for v1.7.x {not specific to live() but all delegated event} `$.each($._data(document, 'events'), function () {
    if (this.delegateCount) console.log(this[0].origType);
});`

Comment: @War10ck true, though I was referring more to live being deprecated / removed in later versions rather than just being evil in general, just wanted to elaborate a little on the first two comments :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try following code:

```
function findEvents(element) {

    var events = element.data('events');
    if (events !== undefined) 
        return events;

    events = $.data(element, 'events');
    if (events !== undefined) 
        return events;

    events = $._data(element, 'events');
    if (events !== undefined)
        return events;

    events = $._data(element[0], 'events');
    if (events !== undefined)
        return events;

    return undefined;
}
```

we're trying to use different ways cause it depends on jquery version.
[JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7v5cf/)

Comment: Could be a good workaround for all (mostly) jq versions if then checking too if event is delegated and of course using 'document' as function argument  {speaking about live()} +1